# AVAssetResourceLoader delegate not set

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates, avfoundation

I've been trying to implement AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate but so far have been unable to successfully set the delegate, causing my delegate code to never get called.

Consider this:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
[asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:[[MyAssetResourceLoaderDelegateCode alloc] init]
                            queue:queue];
NSLog(@"Delegate: %@", asset.resourceLoader.delegate);
```

This code always prints `Delegate: (null)`. How do I set the delegate when the delegate refuses to be set? What am I missing?

This occurs on the simulator and on an iPhone 5s running iOS 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate you associate with this object must adopt the AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate protocol. 
So the code should be like this:

```
@interface YourClass () <AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate>
@end

@implementation YourClass

- (void)someMethod
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"...."];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    [asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:self queue:queue];
}

#pragma mark - AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate methods

- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest
{

}

@end
```

OR

if you have separate delegate MyAssetResourceLoaderDelegateCode somewhere then you have to keep the strong reference to the object MyAssetResourceLoaderDelegateCode you created and pass it as a delegate. When you do [asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:... The resourceLoader is just have a weak reference to the object you made. So, the code can be:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyAssetResourceLoaderDelegateCode *assetObject;

self.assetObject = [MyAssetResourceLoaderDelegateCode new];

[asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:self.assetObject ...];
```

Comment: It does. In my example `MyAssetResourceLoaderDelegateCode` publicly implements the `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` protocol as well as all of its methods, which are currently just log statements and breakpoints to check if they get called (they don't).

Comment: I see, the delegate isn't a strong reference so it was just getting dealloc'd. Now the delegate is getting set correctly, but the delegate object still isn't receiving any messages on the delegate's methods. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need it for audio player? like _playerItem = [AVPlayerItem  playerItemWithAsset:asset]; etc

Comment: No, I'm trying to play [play HLS video while overriding the network code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303611/hls-on-ios-with-custom-buffer-policy?noredirect=1#comment41276364_26303611). I do, however, create an AVPlayerItem like that and pass it to an AVPlayer.